# Image error with WordPress and PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

It may seem a stupid question, but I have a serious problem...

if you could check out orcik.net the thumbnail images do not appear.
I figured out the reason but I don't know how to solve.

```
http://orcik.net/projects/thumb/orcikthumb.php?src=http://orcik.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/mac-safari-search-cache.png
```

If you go to the above link you will get a page not found the error.
However, if you go to the link below you'll get the thumbnail version of the image...

```
http://orcik.net/projects/thumb/orcikthumb.php?src=/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/mac-safari-search-cache.png
```

I'm using this piece of code on WordPress and the line appears like

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"> <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/includes/orcikthumb.php?src=<?php get_thumbnail($post->ID, 'full'); ?>&amp;h=<?php echo get_theme_mod($height); ?>&amp;w=<?php echo get_theme_mod($width); ?>&amp;zc=1" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /> </a>
```

Thus, I believe I can't change the directory of the image. But I could not figure out why I am getting the page not found error. Is that might be CHMOD'es??? or something else??

Thanks

Comment: It'd be a lot less stupid if the question were actually in the title. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be with

```
<?php get_thumbnail($post->ID, 'full'); ?>
```

It generates a full URL instead of a path from the root.
Maybe something to do with the word "full" that appears in there?
I'm not familiar with how this function works, but it sounds like that's where the problem comes from ...

Where did you get this function from?
Maybe a documentation somewhere ...

Try without 'full'.